# How to display the ParseUser that wrote a post?

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

The app is very simple (and complete on IOS) however on the android version  I am unsure how to not only retrieve the ParseUser that wrote the "Post" but display it.

Thank you and forgive my ignorance but I am trying to learn.

Also How would I sort my query so the Newest posts are on top?

```
public class ParseListActivity extends ListActivity {

    List<Posts> posts = new ArrayList<Posts>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.parse_list);

        ParseQuery<Posts> query = new ParseQuery<Posts>("Posts");
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<Posts>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<Posts> list, ParseException e) {
                if (e != null){
                    Toast.makeText(ParseListActivity.this, "Error " + e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                }
                for (Posts post : list){
                    Posts newPost = new Posts();
                    //newPost.setDate(post.getDate());
                    newPost.setContent(post.getContent());
                    posts.add(newPost);
                }

                ArrayAdapter<Posts> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Posts>(ParseListActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, posts);
                setListAdapter(adapter);

            }
        });
    }

}
```

Post.java:

```
@ParseClassName("Posts")
public class Posts extends ParseObject {




    public String getContent(){

        return getString("content");
    }

    public void setContent(String content){

        put("content", content);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return getString("date") + "\n" + getString("content");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a relation to the post of the ParseUser, you can read more about it here: https://www.parse.com/docs/android_guide.

That's one way, the other is to use `getCurrentUser().getObjectId()` on the ParseUser adding the post and save it in a column in your Parse database. And then when receiving your data you can get the ParseUser using the objectId then fetch the dsts you need (such as the name, age).

Hope this helps.